# The size of the virtual HDD file on host differs from the HDD seen from the guest OS

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, hyper-v

In a virtualized environment, there is a number of VM on one host (Windows Server 2019, and Hyper-V is used). When I look at the .vhdx file that is the virtual disk of one VM, it says that it's size (i.e. file size on the host disk) is 31.8Gb. However, when seen from within the guest OS of the VM, the same HDD is described as 91.5GB free of 149GB, also the used space is 57.5GB.

The vhdx file is a single one, how can it be smaller than the total amount of data on the VM?

PS: I don't know whether it is relevant to the issue, but there is single checkpoint for that VM and its file size on the host is 17GB.

Comment: How are you determining the used space?

Comment: @Mokubai Right-click on disk -> properties

Comment: Sorry, I had to ask as it wasn't in your question and there are ways to get disk usage that will show this exact kind of erroneously large size when checked to *actual data*. For example manually scanning all the folders, while ignoring the fact that some folders are simply hardlinks to other folders, will show a much larger amount of data on disk than there actually is. The method you did is what I would have expected to get the right answer so obviously something else (potentially deduplication?) must be going on.

Comment: @Mokubai No problem, you are right, it is an important piece of information, that I intended to put up there, but ultimately forgot.